# Database normalization - foreign keys

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I'm trying to understand database normalization, I understand the general idea, but what is the right approach and what would be excess.

So for example I have a standard employee-department database as the first step.

Tables are

```
EMPLOYEES:
id, first_name, last_name, dob, email, city, address, department_name
```

So, to normalize this as the first step I would move department name to a separate table and would join when necessary as many-to-one.

```
EMPLOYEES:
id, first_name, last_name, dob, email, city, address, department_id
DEPARTMENTS
id, name
```

Would this be enough for normalization or is it better to move all other fields but `department_id` to a second table like `employees_meta`? Imagine if we have 20 more fields in the table describing the employee, what then would be normal?

If we are talking about optimizing a webpage, would the right normalization be to have only the fields we always show when we work with employee table, and all other information we don't use so frequently to be moved to different tables?

Comment: Normalization deals with entities. Everything, which represents a entity in your Model should be seperated (normalized). Your normalization looks ok so far :o)

Comment: Thank you, that was a short and a nice definition, too bad it's in comments :)

Comment: thanx, but why bad because of comment?

Comment: Yes, I would say it was a great answer

Comment: You can vote for that comment ;)

Comment: It's no only about your reputation, but also what others will see when they search for an answer to my question :)

Comment: I will point out that address is in a one to many relationship with the person. People often have multiple addresses.

Comment: @HLGEM you're right, but actually, I have asked this to be more abstract as an example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move city field into separated table, and I think it's enough to be normal. The simple key for [database normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) is avoiding duplicate value and separate it into single table. However, some case of data doesn't need to separate like sex field, it's better to use enum data type then then separate into other table.

Note: To much joining table on query will get lower performance.

Comment: Yeah, totally forgot `city` will be repeated, but talking about `meta` table I've mentioned, is it worth?

Comment: +1 you are right, city looks also to be a entity in this model :o)

Comment: @Vlakarados It alsways depends on your model and the functionality. If it is a important function to have eployees per city, you have with a city entity less pain, if not leave it as it is

Comment: Thank you very much, I never thought of that normalization of one table will help with performance when this table is joined!

Comment: @Vlakarados, about employees_meta, I think it's done by employees table. If you mean it like generic data model with object_id, object_attribute, and value as fields, you will get lower performance for querying data.

Comment: The only factually correct statement in this answer is "To [sic] much joining table on query will get lower performance." And even *that* has nothing to do with normalization.

Answer (score 3):

```
EMPLOYEES:
id, first_name, last_name, dob, email, city, address, department_name
```

> So, to normalize this as the first step I would move department name
>   to a separate table and would join when necessary as many-to-one.

```
EMPLOYEES:
id, first_name, last_name, dob, email, city, address, department_id
DEPARTMENTS
id, name
```

When you normalize based on functional dependencies, your original table *always* ends up with fewer columns. You started with 8, and you finished with 8.

You replaced "department_name" in the original table with "department_id". *No* normalization guideline says "Replace text with ID numbers." Not only does this have *nothing* to do with normalization, it introduces a mandatory join where none was needed before.

That doesn't necessarily mean replacing text with an ID number is the wrong thing to do here. It *does* mean you shouldn't be calling it normalization.  Because it's not.

The *first* step in normalization is to identify the candidate keys and the functional dependencies.

Comment: Good answer, but the first step is to identify functional dependencies relevant to the application domain - something one cannot really get from looking at proposed table layouts. Identifying relevant functional dependencies takes a fair bit of domain disclosure and analysis.

Comment: That's why I said, "The first step in normalization is to identify the candidate keys and the functional dependencies."

Answer (score 2):

Normalization deals with entities. Everything, which represents a entity in your Model should be seperated (normalized).

If you have a table with persons (Firstname, Lastname, etc.) and all theses persons are also users with a username and password to login, then you do not need normalization.

But if only some persons will be users you should normalize to 2 tables (persons, users with person_id as a link to the person entity) and if you need to store person and user entities in several different places (relationships between persons, flag a record with the user who created and last modified) then you better normalize.

So as CatCall stated normalization is not changing a name with an id. That is just creating Lookups.

Answer (score 1):

If you have other information about a certain location along with the city, ex (city, state, zip) then simply store the zip code with employee data. Have a separate table called " US location index" or whatever which will contain a zip code as the primary key, city and state. You can store 2 variants of state name, full and abbreviated. Basically the point is that the city and state are easily determines by a zip code... You can think of it like this..
Each state in the US has many cities, each city has many zip codes, but each zip code identifies a specific city and state combination. For example, on NYC, the zip code 10010 will identify as new York, NY and 10001 will identify as new York, NY. But 11222 will identify as Brooklyn, NY. Hope this helps.